# git replace broken submodule reference throughout entire commit history with correct submodule reference

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

In my main parent repo, I added a submodule normally and committed. I then made a handful of commits to my project unrelated to that submodule.

After those commits, I decided I needed to change my associated email for commits, so I updated my global git config's `user.email`, then `cd`'d into my submodule ran `git rebase -r --root --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author" and pushed.` to retroactively change the email throughout the git history. Then I `cd`d back into my parent repo `../` and pulled the new submodule version with `git submodule update --remote` containing the correct email. I committed this, so the latest version of parent contains the latest version of submodule.

However, it looks like retroactively changing my email throughout the submodules' commit history has regenerated all of the commit hashes. The submodule's hash is now `abc123`, while before it was `xyz456`. When I go to my parent repo on github, I can see at the most recent commit has

```
my_submodule @ abc123
```

which correctly brings me to my submodules git repo on github on click.

But every previous commit in parent shows

```
my_submodule @ xyz456
```

and when I click on that submodule reference, I see the warning

```
This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.
```

This means that if you checkout a previous commit of `parent`, where `my_submodule` still points to `xyz345`, you can see my old email address with `git log` inside of the submodule, which I want to prevent.

I need to retroactively replace all references of `my_submodule` throughout every past commit (after it was added to the repository) with this new reference at commit `abc123`.

Can I use git-filter for this, like people do to retroactively remove a sensitive file throughout all commits?

I want a solution that will look as if `my_submodule` were always pointing to `abc123`, with no extra commits up to this point.

Comment: What I write here is not a complete solution, rather a set of hints; so these are comments, not an answer. 1st you need to get the tip of the old branch (before rebasing) in the submodule (get it from reflog) and the tip (`HEAD`) of the new branch; let's call them `old-master` and `master`. Check that old branch and new branch have equal number of commits: compare the output from `git rev-list --count old-master` and `git rev-list --count master`. *(To be continued…)*

Comment: Create a text file that maps old commit to the new ones: `paste <(git rev-list old-master) <(git rev-list master) >mapping` (the syntax is bash-specific, I hope you use `bash` as your shell). Now the file `mapping` contains 2 columns: old commit and new one separated by a tab. With this file you can run any command in the superproject — `git filter-branch` `git filter-repo`, `git rebase` — check out every commit of the superproject, checkout the corresponding commit in the submodule (usually done automatically), *(To be continued…)*

Comment: …find out the checked out commit in the file `mapping` , find out the new commit, manually checkout the new commit, go back to superproject, add the modified submodule, commit, go to the next commit in the superproject. Could be automated; something like `git rebase --root --exec 'cd submodule && git show --format=%H && find_commits_in_mapping && git checkout new_commit_id && cd .. && git add submodule && git commit --amend'` You only need to implement `find_commits_in_mapping` yourself; should be trivial, really.

Comment: @phd I should mention that this submodule is added to 4 other superprojects, all of which have this same issue now. So I would have to repeat your steps for the other 3. This seems like a lot of tedious, manual stitching, in the absence of an automated script that just works wherever I'm at. At this point, I am considering deleting the `.git` on all super projects and just starting over the commit history here, or abandoning submodules altogether as I often retroactively edit git histories and do not want to deal with SHA1 references getting broken and trapped in the past again.

Comment: Once you create the file `mapping` and a script `find_commits_in_mapping` you can fix all projects with the same commands; create a shell script and run. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @phd Okay, I'll give it a shot. Just to be clear, what exactly is `find_commits_in_mapping` supposed to do? Was it that process you said before about checking out every commit of superproject, check out corresponding commit in submodule, etc... ?

Comment: For an old commit currently checked out at submodule (checked out after the next commit has been checked out in the superproject during `git rebase` or `git filter-branch`) — the commit shown with `git show --format=%H` — the script must find out the new commit in the submodule, the one that was created from the old commit when you had changed email. The new commit must be checked out in the submodule and the change in the submodule must be committed in the superproject. `git filter-branch` or `git rebase` will go to the next commit automatically after the script in `--exec` finishes.

Comment: The script could be very simple — search the old commit hash in the 1st column of the file `mapping`, print out the new hash from the 2nd column. `grep` and/or `awk` would do.