# Fix git submodules after rewriting history of a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have rewritten the history of a submodule quite some time ago and no longer have the original submodule history (so my question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442500/repository-with-submodules-after-rewriting-history-of-submodule))

Can I fix the submodule SHA in the parent repository? Based on the criteria that a submodule SHA in the parent repo points at the most recent commit of the submodule at that time.

Comment: You can work with submodule like with trivial repo, cd to submodule directory and execute command, kinda like that `git checkout master && git pull`. It should help. Then update your parent repo - it will then point to a new submodule's sha.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't much understand how this works. The SHA of the submodule commits has changed and the original SHA are lost for good. How would that fix the issue I have? @Ryan

Comment: I don't see any way to fix this except by relating to commit date/time somehow

Comment: The question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77703619/7976758 and all my comments there stay.

Comment: Could you please make your comments into an easy to use answer? For future readers reference (and for me too `:)` ) @phd